# django WebSocket HANDSHAKING and DISCONNECT

Tags: django, sockets, chat, disconnect

Now I am trying to make chat using socket, but just this message is showing.

[2017/12/08 18:51:07] WebSocket DISCONNECT /chat/prj/chat/ [127.0.0.1:55457]

[2017/12/08 18:51:08] WebSocket HANDSHAKING /chat/prj/chat/ [127.0.0.1:55461]

and get this from inspector

InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
reconnecting-websocket.min.js:1
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8000/chat/prj/chat/.
reconnecting-websocket.min.js:1:1075
The connection to ws://localhost:8000/chat/prj/chat/ was interrupted while the page was loading.
reconnecting-websocket.min.js:1:1075

How to fix this?

here is my consumers.py

```
@channel_session
def ws_connect(message):
    try:
        prefix, label = message['path'].strip('/').split('/')
        if prefix != 'chat':
            log.debug('invalid ws path=%s', message['path'])
            return
        room = Room.objects.get(label=label)
    except ValueError:
        log.debug('invalid ws path=%s', message['path'])
        return
    except Room.DoesNotExist:
        log.debug('ws room does not exist label=%s', label)
        return

    log.debug('chat connect room=%s client=%s:%s path=%s reply_channel=%s',
        room.label, message['client'][0], message['client'][1], message['path'], message.reply_channel)

    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
    Group('chat-'+label, channel_layer=message.channel_layer).add(message.reply_channel)
    message.channel_session['room'] = room.label

@channel_session
def ws_receive(message):
    try:
        label = message.channel_session['room']
        room = Room.objects.get(label=label)
        log.debug('recieved message, room exist label=%s', room.label)

    except KeyError:
        log.debug('no room in channel_session')
        return
    except Room.DoesNotExist:
        log.debug('recieved message, buy room does not exist label=%s', label)
        return

    try:
        data = json.loads(message['text'])
    except ValueError:
        log.debug("ws message isn't json text=%s", text)
        return

    if set(data.keys()) != set(('handle', 'message')):
        log.debug("ws message unexpected format data=%s", data)
        return

    if data:
        log.debug('chat message room=%s handle=%s message=%s',
            room.label, data['handle'], data['message'])
        m = room.messages.create(**data)

        Group('chat-'+label, channel_layer=message.channel_layer).send({'text': json.dumps(m.as_dict())})

@channel_session
def ws_disconnect(message):
    try:
        label = message.channel_session['room']
        room = Room.objects.get(label=label)
        Group('chat-'+label, channel_layer=message.channel_layer).discard(message.reply_channel)
    except (KeyError, Room.DoesNotExist):
        pass
```

and here is chat.js

```
$(function() {
    var ws_scheme = window.location.protocol == "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
    var chatsock = new ReconnectingWebSocket(ws_scheme + '://' + window.location.host + "/chat" + window.location.pathname);

    chatsock.onmessage = function(message) {
        var data = JSON.parse(message.data);
        var chat = $("#chat")
        var ele = $('<tr></tr>')

        ele.append(
            $("<td></td>").text(data.timestamp)
        )
        ele.append(
            $("<td></td>").text(data.handle)
        )
        ele.append(
            $("<td></td>").text(data.message)
        )

        chat.append(ele)
    };

    $("#chatform").on("submit", function(event) {
        var message = {
            handle: $('#handle').val(),
            message: $('#message').val(),
        }
        chatsock.send(JSON.stringify(message));
        $("#message").val('').focus();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if the JavaScript that is throwing this error were also included. As well as the routes that connect to each of these functions.

Comment: I uploaded my chat.js file. and do you need routing.py file too?